# Close ManagementScope connection

Tags: c#, wmi

I have the following code which connects to a remote machine in order to perform WMI queries.

```
var managementScope = new ManagementScope
{
    Path = new ManagementPath(@"\\hostname\root\cimv2")
};

managementScope.Connect();
```

Once I am finished querying the remote machine, I wish to close the connection.

Per the documentation for the [ManagementScope.IsConnected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.isconnected(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> A scope is disconnected after creation until someone explicitly calls Connect, or uses the scope for any operation that requires a live connection. Also, the scope is disconnected from the previous connection whenever the identifying properties of the scope are changed.

In order to try to close the connection, I added the following code:

```
managementScope.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Empty);
```

However, despite having changed the properties of the ManagementScope object, the connection to the remote machine (6.7.8.9) remains established as evidenced by netstat on the host machine:

```
TCP    1.2.3.4:12345      6.7.8.9:135       TIME_WAIT
TCP    1.2.3.4:12345      6.7.8.9:49154     ESTABLISHED
```

Once the program exits, the connection drops to `TIME_WAIT` and finally exits.

Since I intend to connect to many computers during the lifetime of the program, this could theoretically cause a bottleneck or exhaustion of available TCP ports.

How can the WMI TCP connection be closed?

Comment: There is no explicit way to close it, just try making your `managementScope` object = `null` and wait for GC to clean it up